# How do I change majorDimension value for a particular range in batchGet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to pull information from google sheets but there is one problem where I want to pull different ranges with different dimensions.

```
For Example:
/* This is something I want to achieve */

spreadsheetId: '',

// This code won't work.
ranges: [
{
range: 'Sheet1',
majorDimension: 'ROWS'
},
{
range: 'Sheet2',
majorDimension: 'COLUMNS'
}]
```

I Want to pull info something like the above example I have written. Is there a way that I can achieve it?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this might resolve in the future, unfortunately, in the current stage, ``majorDimension`` cannot be used multiple values by one API call. I apologize for this situation. For example, as a current workaround, how about requesting 2 times using ``ROWS`` and ``COLUMNS``?

Comment: @Tedinoz See [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get#query-parameters)

Comment: @TheMaster Noted. Should have done more research myself!;)